# "Trying to get property of non-object" in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Below I got my middleware that updates IP of the user.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class UserMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
         $this->auth = $auth;
    }
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        User::where('id', $this->auth->user()->id)->update(['last_visit_ip' => '231']);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Some notification is popping me up `"Trying to get property of non-object"` Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What line? One of your objects is not an object.

Comment: User::where .....

Comment: `auth->user()` can return `null` ... also if you **can** get the authed user, you can just call update on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
User::where('id', $this->auth->user()->id)->update(['last_visit_ip' => '231']);
```

to this

```
User::where('id', Auth::id())->update(['last_visit_ip' => '231']);
```

and import this on top `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Answer (score 1):

If there current user isn't authenticated you will get a `null` from the `user()` call off the `AuthManager`/Guard. Trying to access a property on `null` will give you that error.

If you want to use this middleware as is, you have to make sure you have the `auth` middleware assigned before it. You are expecting there to be an authenticated user, so you have to make sure that is the case.

The best way to do that is to use the `auth` middleware that will check if the current user is authenticated and let them pass through. That will guarantee that when this middleware is ran you absolutely have a currently authenticated user.